# <br> tags screws up my data using scrapy and python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text of the reviews on Amazon using scrapy. The problem is that when a review consists of multiple enters, the text in a span element is separated by < br > tags. So, when I want to scrape the first review I use this line of code:

```
response.css('span.a-size-base.review-text::text').extract_first()
```

This does not give me all the text of the review, but only the text between the < span > element and the first < br > element.

I know that when I replace "extract_first()" by "extract()", I will get all the text. However, this also gives me the text of the other reviews.

So basically, the extract() method returns an array with the elements being separated by < br > tags. I need it to be separated by the < span > tags.

Is there a way to scrape all text between the open < span > element and the closing < /span > element?

**example of HTML code:**

```
< span data-hook="review-body" class="a-size-base review-text">
    "I like this product, the reasons why are explained below"
    < br >
    < br >
    "1. It looks nice" 
    < br >
    "2. I love it"
< /span >
```

**What it looks like on the site:**

I like this product, the reasons why are explained below

1. It looks nice
2. I love it

**Output I will get using extract_first():**

"I like this product, the reasons why are explained below"

**Output I will get using extract() (note that it consists of three elements):**

"I like this product, the reasons why are explained below",
"1. It looks nice",
"2. I love it"

**Output I want to get (only one element, the review itself):**

"I like this product, the reasons why are explained below 1. It looks nice 2. I love it"

Answer (score 1):

Use extract() and join the list.

```
>>> text=["I like this product, the reasons why are explained below", "1. It looks nice", "2. I love it"]
>>> " ".join(text)
'I like this product, the reasons why are explained below 1. It looks nice 2. I love it'
```

Comment: I used one review as an example. If there are more reviews on the page, the output of extract() will consist of more reviews. So if I would use join(text), I would have the text of all reviews combined in one element.

Comment: Is there a problem still?

Comment: yes, maybe my question is not clear. but when there are for example 2 reviews on the page and I will use join(text). I will get the 2 reviews together, but I want to have them separate.

Comment: If the returned list contains two reviews where the first two elements are the text of the first review and the other three elements are the text of the second review. I want to have a list of 2 elements where the first is the first review and the second element is the second review. I know you can do this manually but without knowing up front how many enters the reviewer has in his review this will not work.